# Torsion free Chern connections and Kähler manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, connections, hermitian-manifolds

Let $(M,h)$ be an Hermitian manifold and let $\nabla$ be the associated Chern connection. Is it true that $(M,h)$ is Kähler if and only if $\nabla$ is torsion free?

Comment: The Chern connection is always metric. If it is also torsionfree, then it agrees with the Levi-Civita connection. According to W. Ballmann's "Kähler geometry", Thm 4.17, this is one of a number of conditions equivalent to being Kähler.